# Encryption Iris ODBC 64 Bit

Tags: intersystems-iris

We have ODBC 32bit Encryption working on our database with a SSLDEFs.ini file.  However 64 bit ODBC Encryption will not work and give generic error, same error if the ini file is not there for 32BIT.

We have copied the ini file to the 64bit folder?  Any ideas please?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

input by Katherine Reid Jul 7,2021

Have you tried specifying the location and name of the SSLDefs.ini file with the *ISC_SSLconfigurations* environment variable?
This is an alternate way of specifying where the configuration file is.